# Where is all this white space coming from?

Tags: html, css

Working on a project for my web design class and can't figure out where all this white space is coming from. Everything needs to touch each other yet I think I have extra padding somewhere but I just can't seem to pinpoint it. Here is all my code. Also, I'd like to know how to get rid of the bullets in my `<ul>` on the left. I've tried `list-style-type:none` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>SylviaGunter WEB-210 Project 6</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Peralta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand|Peralta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href=01%20-%20Large%20CSS.css>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="02 - Medium CSS">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="03 - Small CSS">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="04 - Print CSS">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="05 - IE"> 

</head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <body>
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>Best TV Ever</h1>

        <div class="topnav"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">50s</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">60s</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">70s</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">80s</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">90s</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>





[insert menu toggle here]
[insert menu checkbox here]





<aside class="sidebar1">

   Best Prime Time Shows
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Alice</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">All In The Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Barney Miller</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Beverly Hillbillies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bewitched</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Bob Newhart Show</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Brady Bunch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gilligan's Island</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Good Times</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Love Boat</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mary Tyler Moore</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">M*A*S*H</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Maude</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One Day At A Time</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Petticoat Junction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Soap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Taxi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What's Happening</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Welcome Back Kotter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WKRP In Cincinatti</a></li>
</ul>

            </aside>


<article class="main">

<h2>The Genius of Krofft</h2>

<h3>H.R. Pufnstuff</h3>

<p> <img src="hrpufnstuff.jpg" alt="hrpufnstuff" height="150" width="200">H.R. Pufnstuf centered on a shipwrecked boy named Jimmy. He and his friend, a talking flute named Freddy, take a ride on a mysterious boat, which promised adventures across the sea, to Living Island. The Mayor of Living Island was a friendly and helpful dragon named H.R. Pufnstuf. The boat was actually owned and controlled by a wicked witch named Wilhelmina W. Witchiepoo who rode on a broomstick-like vehicle called the Vroom Broom. She used the boat to lure Jimmy and Freddy to her castle on Living Island, where she was going to take Jimmy prisoner and steal Freddy. But Pufnstuf found out about her plot and was able to rescue Jimmy when he leaped out of the enchanted boat with Freddy and swam ashore.</p>

<h3>Lidsville</h3>


<p><img src="lidsville.jpg" alt="lidsville" height="150" width="200">
The show involved a teenage boy named Mark who fell into the hat of Merlo the Magician and arrived in Lidsville, a land of living hats. The hats on the show are depicted as having the same characteristics as the humans who would normally wear them.</p>

<h3>The Bugaloos</h3>


<p><img src="bugaloos.jpg" alt="bugaloos" height="150" width="200">The Bugaloos featured a musical group composed of four British-accented teenagers, who lived in fictional Tranquility Forest. They wore insect-themed outfits with antennae and wings which allowed them to fly. They were constantly beset by the evil machinations of Benita Bizarre, played by comedienne Martha Raye.</p>

<h3>Land of the Lost</h3>


<p><img src="landlost.jpg" alt="landlost" height="150" width="200">Land of the Lost details the adventures of the Marshall family (father Rick and his teenage children Will and Holly) who are trapped in an alternate universe inhabited by dinosaurs, a primate-type people called Pakuni, and aggressive humanoid/lizard creatures called Sleestak.</p>

<h3>Sigmund the Sea Monster</h3>


<p><img src="sigmund.jpg" alt="sigmund"  height="150" width="200">The show centered on two brothers, Johnny and Scott Stuart, who discover Sigmund, a friendly young sea monster who had been thrown out by his comically dysfunctional undersea family for refusing to frighten people. The boys hide Sigmund in their clubhouse.</p>

            </article>



   <aside class="sidebar2">
  Best Superhero Shows
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Batman (1966)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Bionic Woman (1976)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Electra Woman and Dyna Girl (1976)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Greatest American Hero (1981)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Incredible Hulk (1977)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Isis (1975)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shazam! (1974)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Six Million Dollar Man (1974)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wonder Woman (1976)</a></li>
</ul>
            </aside>




<div id="footer">
Stop watching TV and write some code!
            </div>



</body>
</html>
```

```
body{

}


.banner h1{
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Peralta;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 150px;}

h2{
    font-family: Peralta;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

p{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
    height:130px;
}

img{
    float: left;

    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;}



.topnav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
 float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -120px;
}


.topnav ul li a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 10px;
width: 100px;
    font-size: 20px}

*{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar1{
    float: left;
    width: 265px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
   background: url(sidebar1background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 1000px;

}

.main{

    float: left;
    width: 60%;
     padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    background-color: #d4ff80;
    height: 1000px;

}

.sidebar2{
    float: right;
    width: 265px;
    padding-right: 30px;
     padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    background: url(sidebar2background.jpg)right top;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 1000px;
    list-style-type: none;


}

.sidebar1 a:link{
    background-color:  #c1c1a4;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border:1px solid white;
    display: block;
    background-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
     padding: 5px 5px 5px 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: darkgreen;
    padding-right: 20px;
}



#footer{
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: A document cant have two `body` tags

Comment: And after fixing that, please create a [mcve] _online_ somewhere (jsfiddle, codepen, …)

Comment: And spaces in URLs are something you should avoid too.

Comment: //jsfiddle.net/a0ht06y7/ here is the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have built-in styles adding some spaces (paddings & margins) by default, which are different across browsers.
You will need to do a [reset css](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reset+css):

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

About your bullets, you need to specify for both lists:

```
.sidebar1 ul, .sidebar2 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* OR */
aside ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Great! The bullets are gone. However there is still about an inch of white space between the center content and the right sidebar. The only thing that happened when I add the reset css code is it moved the inside ul all the way to the left edge of the side bar background. I need to close that space. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: You are setting: `20px` wide padding to `.main`. Also, you are mixing fixed with percent widths, what will make it work only in a small range of resolution width.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the sidebar bullet list use:

```
.sidebar1 ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```